# Attach reference frames to models

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-model

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am currently setting up a simulation in Gazebo 2.0. In this scene, there will be a number of objects that the robot will need to interact with.

Is there a way to define coordinate frames relative to the models in the scene, and make them available through TF? If so, how would I go about implementing them?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5304/attach-reference-frames-to-models/) by [Peaches491](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/626/peaches491/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-01-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can use a `robot_state_publisher` to send the robots state to tf...
[`robot_state_publisher`](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_state_publisher)

for that you will need a gazebo plugin that publishes the joint states

This can be easily done by a `ros_controll` plugin as described here:

[`ROS_Control_with_Gazebo`](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/ROS_Control_with_Gazebo)

(the important thing is the `joint_state_controller`...)

I hope this help

---

Originally posted by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) with karma: 881 on 2014-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0